# PHP search filter function doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created search filter function in php form. Fetched data from mysql in table. All query and others written well. But search function doesn't work.

```
<?php
    require_once 'init.php';
    include 'header.php';
    include 'navigation.php';

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
      $valSearch = $_POST['searchButton'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE CONCAT ('id','commandName','commandDesc','status') LIKE '%".$valSearch."%'";
      $featured = filterTable($query);
    }else{
      $query = "SELECT * FROM mainTable";
      $featured = filterTable($query);
    }

    function filterTable($query){
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","linuxcommanddictionary");
      $filter_result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
      return $filter_result;
    }

 ?>
 <form action = "index.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Linux Fedora OS</h3><hr>
        <button type="submit" name ="searchButton" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        <input type="text" name = "search" class="form-control" placeholder="Хайх үгээ бичнэ үү">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Command Name</th>
                        <th>Command Description</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)): ?>
                      <tr>
                          <td><?=$result['id']; ?></td>
                          <td><?=$result['commandName']; ?></td>
                          <td><?=$result['commandDesc']; ?></td>
                          <td><?=$result['status']; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    include 'footer.php';
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is Database structure.

```
create table if not exists mainTable(
   id int auto_increment,
   commandName varchar(255),
   commandDesc varchar(255),
   status int(2),
   primary key(id)
)
```

Comment: it does not work is not a good explanation from a developer. What errors do you get?

Comment: also it seems you need to pass your connection variable as a global variable in your filter table function

Comment: Any error doesn't appeared.

Comment: and also : $valSearch = $_POST['searchButton']; then echo it, what does it say ? and what about : $valSearch = $_POST['search']; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SInce you said you do not have any errors, try the following:

1- Run your query manually via your phpmyadmin and see if you get any results.

2- PAss your connection variable as a global variable. Read more on variable [scopes here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to better understand the concepts involved

```
 function filterTable($query){
   global $connect;
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","linuxcommanddictionary");
      $filter_result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
      // fetch results here as mysqli_query returns true/false.
      $final_results = array();
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($filter_result,MYSQLI_NUM)){
         $final_results[] = $row;
      }
      return $final_results;
    }
```

3- turn on error_reporting to see if anything comes up

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are calling the mysqli connection inside a function and then ask for mysqli_fetch_assoc() outside of the 'Scope' of the function.

1. learn scope http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You can 
-Move your while loop inside your function and return an 'copy' of the array ( memory suck up).
-or-
Create you connector in the global scope and call 'global' in your function to fetch the data (cpu suck up) -or- move everything all tohether in the global scope.

Comment: Your question lack alot, i even tried to edit it and you don't have enough 'content' to even be edited. Please do your homework so we can help you better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks! understood :)